# Can't insert js programmatically if it uses document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, javascript-injection

I am trying to insert js files programmatically, using jquery and something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://someurl/test.js';
$('body').append(script);
```

It works fine, if test.js contains an `alert` or some simple code it works fine, but if the file test.js contains `document.write`, and the file including the js is hosted on another domain than test.js (or localhost), nothing happens and firebug shows the error :

> A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external
>   script was ignored.

If the test.js and the file that include it are hosted on the same domain, on chrome it still wont work but on firefox the `document.write` gets executed fine but the page stays "loading" forever and sniffer show request to all the files with "pending" status.

**What other methods to include js files programmatically could I try?**

Comment: The problem isn't how you're including the file, it is that there is a `document.write()` being executed after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 4):

use `innerHTML` instead of using `document,write`.

and use following code to register script,

```
(function() {
    var jq = document.createElement('script');
    jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.async = true;
    jq.src = 'http://someurl/test.js';
    var s = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(jq, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Document.write is ONLY for synchronous tasks when the html is loaded (for the very first time), never for asynchronous tasks like the one you are trying to do.

Comment: That is correct; but if can modify the external script, use innerHTML instead of document.write like @ChamikaSandamal said.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is dynamically insert a `<script>` DOM element into the HEAD element. I had this script sitting around. As an example, it's a race condition, but you get the idea. Call `load_js` with the URL. This is done for many modern APIs, and it's your best friend for cross-domain JavaScript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var load_js = function(data, callback)
            {
                    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

                    var script = document.createElement("script");
                    script.type = "text/javascript";
                    script.src = data;
                    head.appendChild(script);

                    if(callback != undefined)
                            callback();
            }

            load_js("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js");

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').html('loaded');
            }, 1000);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Eric, 1>This loads the jQuery, but if I pass any function as a second parameter to load_js() that function is not called after loading of js. 2> At what moment load_js and setTimeout are called ? Can you tell the flow of execution here ?

Comment: Umesh, the 2nd parameter isn't called after loading the JS, just after the DOM element is injected. In order to get a callback after a script is loaded, you want JSONP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP Google's JS API handles that for you if you use it, but the above was only an example. Here: http://925html.com/code/using-googles-ajax-apis/ Once you have jQuery, you can inject more <script>'s into <head> with jQuery with something like this: $('<script>').attr('src', 'mysite.com/myjs.js').appendTo('head');

Comment: Eric, This is really wonderful stuff you said :) I am following your blog..why don't you write many more stuffs like that..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with your approach to inserting JavaScript. `document.write` just sucks a little bit. It is only for synchronous tasks, so putting a `document.write` in a separate script file is asking for trouble. People do it anyway. The solution I've seen most often for this is to override `document.write`.